# How to pass boost::log::expressions::smessage to nlohmann::json constructor?

Tags: c++, json, boost, c++17, nlohmann-json

I have a code similar to this:
`const auto jsonFormatter = boost::log::expressions::stream << boost::log::expressions::smessage;`

I want to escape the message using `nlohmann::json`, something like:
`nlohmann::json json{boost::log::expressions::smessage};`

I can do following to convert `boost::log::expressions::smessage` to `std::string`:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << boost::log::expressions::smessage;
std::string message = ss.str();
nlohmann::json json{message};
```

, but I need to put it inside the formatter, because the
`const auto jsonFormatter = boost::log::expressions::stream << nlohmann::json{boost::log::expressions::smessage};`
can't convert the `boost::log::expressions::smessage` argument to any `nlohmann::json` constructor.

Any suggestions how to make it work?

Comment: Ok, I solved it and will post it as soon as I finish it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate help and the other answers, which may be better in other cases, but long story short, I tried a lot of solutions and went with this one in the end (I can update it if it can be improved):

```
#include <boost/phoenix/bind/bind_function.hpp>
..
nlohmann::json EscapeMessage(
    boost::log::value_ref<std::string, boost::log::expressions::tag::smessage> const& message)
{
    return message ? nlohmann::json(message.get()) : nlohmann::json();
}
..
const auto jsonFormatter = boost::log::expressions::stream << boost::phoenix::bind(&EscapeMessage, boost::log::expressions::smessage.or_none())
boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout, boost::log::keywords::format = jsonFormatter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Log formatters look like normal C++, but they are expression templates that compose deferred calleable that do the corresponding action.

Here's how you can make a wrapper expression that knows how to do this:

```
namespace {
    struct as_json_t {
        template <typename E> auto operator[](E fmt) const {
            return expr::wrap_formatter(
                [fmt](logging::record_view const& rec,
                              logging::formatting_ostream& strm) {
                    logging::formatting_ostream tmp;
                    std::string text;
                    tmp.attach(text);
                    fmt(rec, tmp);

                    strm << nlohmann::json{text};
                });
        }
    };

    inline constexpr as_json_t as_json;
} // namespace
```

Now you can make your formatter e.g.

```
logging::formatter formatter = expr::stream
    << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S.%f") << " "
    << logging::trivial::severity
    << " - " << as_json[expr::stream << expr::smessage]
    ;
```

ANd the result is e.g.

```
2021-01-15, 23:34:08.489173 error - ["this is an error message"]
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w03rPDPJdJ7kMDBN)**

- File `simpleLogger.h`

  ```
   #ifndef _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_SIMPLELOGGER_H
   #define _HOME_SEHE_PROJECTS_STACKOVERFLOW_SIMPLELOGGER_H

   #pragma once
   #define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK \
       1 // necessary when linking the boost_log library dynamically

   #include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

   // the logs are also written to LOGFILE
   #define LOGFILE "logfile.log"

   // just log messages with severity >= SEVERITY_THRESHOLD are written
   #define SEVERITY_THRESHOLD logging::trivial::warning

   // register a global logger
   BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<
                                       boost::log::trivial::severity_level>)

   // just a helper macro used by the macros below - don't use it in your code
   #define LOG(severity) \
       BOOST_LOG_SEV(logger::get(), boost::log::trivial::severity)

   // ===== log macros =====
   #define LOG_TRACE LOG(trace)
   #define LOG_DEBUG LOG(debug)
   #define LOG_INFO LOG(info)
   #define LOG_WARNING LOG(warning)
   #define LOG_ERROR LOG(error)
   #define LOG_FATAL LOG(fatal)

   #endif
  ```
- File `simpleLogger.cpp`

  ```
   #include "simpleLogger.h"

   #include <boost/core/null_deleter.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/core/core.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/char_decorator.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/expressions/formatters/date_time.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/sinks/sync_frontend.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/sinks/text_ostream_backend.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/sources/severity_logger.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/support/date_time.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
   #include <boost/log/utility/setup/common_attributes.hpp>
   #include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
   #include <fstream>

   namespace logging = boost::log;
   namespace src     = boost::log::sources;
   namespace expr    = boost::log::expressions;
   namespace sinks   = boost::log::sinks;
   namespace attrs   = boost::log::attributes;

   BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)
   BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(severity, "Severity", logging::trivial::severity_level)

   namespace {
       struct as_json_t {
           template <typename E> auto operator[](E fmt) const {
               return expr::wrap_formatter(
                   [fmt](logging::record_view const& rec,
                                 logging::formatting_ostream& strm) {
                       logging::formatting_ostream tmp;
                       std::string text;
                       tmp.attach(text);
                       fmt(rec, tmp);

                       strm << nlohmann::json{text};
                   });
           }
       };

       inline constexpr as_json_t as_json;
   } // namespace

   BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(logger, src::severity_logger_mt) {
       src::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger;

       // add attributes
       logger.add_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock()); // each log line gets a timestamp

       // add a text sink
       using text_sink = sinks::synchronous_sink<sinks::text_ostream_backend>;
       boost::shared_ptr<text_sink> sink = boost::make_shared<text_sink>();

       // add a logfile stream to our sink
       sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
           boost::make_shared<std::ofstream>(LOGFILE));

       // add "console" output stream to our sink
       sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
           boost::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::clog, boost::null_deleter()));

       // specify the format of the log message
       logging::formatter formatter = expr::stream
           << expr::format_date_time(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S.%f") << " "
           << logging::trivial::severity
           << " - " << as_json[expr::stream << expr::smessage]
           ;

       sink->set_formatter(formatter);
       // only messages with severity >= SEVERITY_THRESHOLD are written
       sink->set_filter(severity >= SEVERITY_THRESHOLD);

       // "register" our sink
       logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);

       return logger;
   }
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "simpleLogger.h"

   int main() {
       LOG_TRACE << "this is a trace message";
       LOG_DEBUG << "this is a debug message";
       LOG_WARNING << "this is a warning message";
       LOG_ERROR << "this is an error message";
       LOG_FATAL << "this is a fatal error message";
       return 0;
   }
  ```

Prints

```
2021-01-15, 23:50:03.130250 warning - ["this is a warning message"]
2021-01-15, 23:50:03.130327 error - ["this is an error message"]
2021-01-15, 23:50:03.130354 fatal - ["this is a fatal error message"]
```

Comment: Added demo **[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/w03rPDPJdJ7kMDBN)**

Answer (score 1):

In addition to **sehe**'s answer, you could achieve the JSON-like format using Boost.Log components. The essential part is the `c_decor` [character decorator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/expressions.html#log.detailed.expressions.formatters.decorators), which ensures that its output can be used as a C-style string literal.

```
namespace expr = boost::log::expressions;

const auto jsonFormatter =
    expr::stream << "[\""
       << expr::c_decor[ expr::stream << expr::smessage ]
       << "\"]";
```

First, `c_decor` will escape any control characters in the messages to C-style escape sequences, like \n, \t. It will also escape double quote characters. Then, the surrounding brackets and double quotes are added to make the output compatible with JSON format.

If you have non-ASCII characters in your log messages and you want the formatted log records to be strictly ASCII, you can use `c_ascii_decor` instead of `c_decor`. In addition to what `c_decor` does, it will also escape any bytes greater than 127 to their hex escape sequences, e.g. \x8c.

Comment: Thanks. But I think it produces different than original string when I JSON unescape it, right? Because it does more changes than JSON escape, correct?

Comment: @LukasSalich I don't know exactly what `nlohmann::json` does. Maybe it escapes different characters from `c_decor`. But `c_decor` should produce a string that is compatible with JSON, so you should be able to parse it with any conforming JSON parser, if that is your intention. After parsing, the string should be equivalent to the original, provided that the parser unescapes C-style escape sequences.